# Disable mouse using touch screen interface

Tags: tkinter, touch, mouse, disable

I created a window interface and I disabled the mouse, it is no longer visible, but the result is that the focus remains in the hidden position where it is and therefore the buttons are visible with focus (change color). I searched a lot but I found nothing, although I could remove the color change of the keys ...
Thanks in advance for solution

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can better help. Also, your problem is a little unclear. Do you mean that the focus changes when you move the invisible mouse? Have you tried changing the buttons' colors for "focused" state, so that "focused" looks no different than "not focused"?

Comment: Yes, the mouse is invisible (app.config(cursor="none")), but the cursor at position there is, 
 is only ghost the arrow. So, when you leave finger from touch screen and and the menu switch on new frame, if a button of the new frame appear in the mouse position, it will be focused whin over color (needs a video to explain it better). Perhaps le best solution is to change all the over buttons color (but in these way I have to handle different devices for use of mouse/touch )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the problem that occurs on any application with touch screen where the cursor is hidden with "app.config(cursor="none")", the cursor continues to "work" in background on the current position with the focus on the buttons, even if it is not visible; don't need a code to explain this but rather a video if is not clear